# Java tiled based rendering, possible to move the already painted?

Tags: java, paint, move, tiles

So if I don't clear my painting area it will just paint over there I paint and leave the other parts there I haven't painted as the old was. So can I take what's already is painted and move it to the left for example. So I can fit an new set of tiles on the right without needing to repaint all of it?

Or am I getting at this at the wrong angle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you're describing but there's no point to it that I can think of. Rendering part of the screen after some offset will yield no real improvement.

I'll assume you're trying to do this for faster rendering.

Most games do 2 things for faster tiled rendering.

1. Clipping. Don't render what's offscreen. Don't render what's underneath other opaque tiles if you're rendering 2.5D.
2. Rendering sections of your map to bigger images, then render these bigger images instead of each tile image individually.

The second is more difficult, and has limitations. For example, you'd need to rerender the larger images if your tile content changes. This would probably get you the most improvement.

Comment: I done a test where I just put a 4000x4000 image as the world. Now I got it down to 3200x3200 as a minimum of the 1080p resolution. This cause I don't need to rerender if I just turn the world around (it's scroll based world with rotation). So the size is based on how much space the resolution needs to turn around and added a tile width on that. What leave me a tile movement in all directions before I need to update the tiles on the side which I'm traveling to.

Comment: I just came to think of, if I use this buffer with all tiles rendered into it could then take the graphics object of that buffer and use the drawImage method to draw the buffer over it self but change the position?

Comment: @Andreas That's what I've described in point 2, yes. Its a more efficient way to render tiles.

Comment: Okay didn't get that one since I wrote it. Just to be clear I can draw the buffer to it self?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by draw the buffer to itself... images can be rendered to other images. Images can be rendered to the gui, and the gui can be rendered to images so... your answer is yes. You can render pretty much any buffer to any other buffer.

Comment: What I mean is "BufferedImage exampleImage" and if I do this "Graphics g = exampleImage.createGraphics()" and then this "g.drawImage(exampleImage, 200, 0, null)"

Comment: Yes, you can do that.